# ASP.Net MVC 4, kendo UI Scheduler customize add edit popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm new to to Kendo UI and currently struggling to find a way to customize the add edit popup. And help and guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to customize the edit form

1. Override it completely via the [editor.template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#configuration-editable.template) option
2. Customize the existing one by handling the [edit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#events-edit) event.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it didn't work. May be because I'm using MVC4.